# How to take First letter from the string with comma separated?

Tags: javascript

I have one array and I store comma separated strings in the array. Now I want to take in the string every first letter take from the string with comma separated.
For ex => `Abc, Xyz, Hji` so now I want `A, X, H`.

Here below listed my code and array.

This is my code =>

```
var ArryString = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {            
    ArryString.push(data[i].Str);
}
```

Current o/p =>

```
     "Abc"  
    "Xyz,Hji,Lol",
    "Uyi,Mno"
```

my expacted o/p= >

```
    "A" 
    "X,H,L"
     "U,M"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything - eg have you researched how to split by commas?  Or alternatively how to get the first letter of a string?  Those are two smaller subproblems that you should solve independently of each other then put the pieces together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not looking good and amateurish but understandable.

```js
var ArryString = [];
var data = ["Abc", "Xyz,Hji,Lol", "Uyi,Mno"];
var index=0;
for (var k in data){
var a=data[k].split(",");
ArryString[index]=a[0].charAt(0);
if(a.length > 1)
    for (var l=1 ;l<a.length ; l++)
        ArryString[index]+=","+a[l].charAt(0);
index++;
}

console.log(ArryString);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could split the strings and take only the first character with a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and join the first characters for a string. Then map the new string for a new array.

```js
var data = ["Abc", "Xyz,Hji,Lol", "Uyi,Mno"];
    result = data.map(s => s
        .split(',')
        .map(([c]) => c)
        .join());
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great answer Nina. How do I read the idiom `map(([s]) => s)`?

Comment: @another-guy, it's a destructuring assignment, where the first item of the callback is treated as iterable and then it takes the first element of it.

Comment: and what if I wanted to take an `n`-th element instead? Would I be able to use the destructuring assignment still?

Comment: for the `n`-th element, i would use the classic index.

Comment: So what is the reasoning behind using the destructuring assignment for the case where `n === 0` ? (I'm new to JS and trying to understand the idioms)

Comment: it's just another type of accessing an array without taking an index for the access. it works with sparse array as well, like `[, c]` for the second element. for other elements, it takes a longer code to write, then i would use the index for it.

Comment: Thanks, with the example of the sparse array it makes more sense now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use charAt method Return the first character of a string.

```
var newString = [];
for (var i=0; i< newString.length; i++)
{
    newString.push(ArrayString[i].charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **String.charAt()** method *for each* string in the array and *push* the first character to a new array.

Example function:-

```
function takeFirstChar(arr){
  var new_arr = [];
  arr.forEach(function(el){
  var firstLetter = el.charAt(0)
    new_arr.push(firstLetter);
  });
  return new_arr;
}

takeFirstChar(['hello','cruel','world']);
//Output-> ['h','c','w']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example :

```js
// We've got an array of comma separated worlds
// Sometimes we've got one, sometimes several
data=["Hello","i","have","one,array","and,i","store","comma,separated,string,in","the","array"];
// We want to ouput the same pattern but keeping the initial letter only
var result = [];
var items = [];
var aChar;
// We loop thru the data array
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
  // We make a small array with the content of each cell
        items = data[i].split(",");
  for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) { // We loop thru the items array
   aChar = items[j].charAt(0); // We take the first letter only
   if (aChar!="") // If the item/work was not empty the we keep only the initial letter in our items array
    items[j] = aChar;
  }
  result.push(items.join(",")); // we store comma separated first letters in our result array
    }

console.log(result)
```